# HTML5 IE fix not working

Tags: html, excanvas

I have created a bar chart which is a improvement of bar graph on [HTML5Lab](http://html5laboratory.com/creating-a-bar-chart-with-canvas.php). I have included the excanvas.js but still it doesn't seems to show anything at all. My bar graph can be found [here](http://intercepter.comli.com/example3.html)

Note: This graph is working in all other browsers.

Please help me out my project deadline is near and this IE is giving me nightmares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok resolved by using the latest excanvas.js code from svn trunk. The code on google [project home](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) is very old it was last updated in 2009. Got the idea from this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=69)

For those who don't know you can get the latest svn trunk code from :

http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js

Answer (score 1):

One issue. You will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers without a doctype. Right now you are in quirks mode. Add this to your very first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thanks Rob but latest version seems to resolve the issue in IE8 and IE9

Comment: @antnewbee - For now but you will continue to run into problems until you insert the doctype. All modern web pages require one and IE performs even worse than it always does without one.

Comment: You are right. after I inserted doctype it is now working with all IE versions :)